# Maple says that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} (xy) = 0$?

Tags: calculus, maple

For some reason maple claims that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} (xy) = 0$ as seen below

[image]

But I am very sure that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} (xy) = 0$ is wrong and should be $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} (xy) = y$? So what is going on?

Comment: 1. This is probably not the right place to ask this. 2. I don't know Maple, but if it's like Mathematica, then `xy` is not `x×y`, but rather a different variable itself (.e.g., `var` would be a variable with name `var`, not `v×a×r`). I don't know if this is the case, but it might be.

Comment: You can have variable names longer than one character, so $xy$ literally means the variable named "xy" to Maple. $x*y$ tells Maple that you mean to multiply two variables, one named "x" and the other named "y".

Comment: @CameronWilliams Yup, José just made me realize that. But it isn't incorrect to write $f(x,y) = xy$ in real life, right? I have seen so many professors do that. Just to be sure

Comment: @npp You're correct, but implicitly we're suppressing the $*$ that truly exists between $x$ and $y$ when we do that. Proper rigorous mathematical notation would dictate that we write it as $x*y$ buuuut that would be ridiculously cumbersome, so we don't.

Comment: Mathematica allows you to write "x y" (with a space), but in Maple, and most programming languages, you need the multiplication sign: "x*y".

Comment: Maple allows input with multiplication implicitly denoted by a space, for its so-called 2D Input mode (like the black input in your image). In other words, `x y` with a space. In Maple's (red plaintext) 1D notation you'd need the explicit multiplication sign, ie. `x*y`. For new users the default is 2D Input, but you can change that as a GUI preference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont work with Maple, but I suspect that you should type `diff(x*y,x)` instead of `diff(xy,x)`.

Comment: Wow - well done! It worked